# Ng-repeat one element multiple times based on its properties

Tags: angularjs

I have an object like this:

```
$scope.cars=[
    {'element':'Ford','count':3},
    {'element':'Honda','count':2},
    {'element':'Ferrari','count':1},
    {'element':'Delorean','count':6}
];
```

What I would like to achieve is to repeat every element n times where n is defined by its property `count`

I have achieved it like this

```
   <li ng-repeat="car in cars">
      <p2 ng-if="car.count >0">{{car.element}}</p2>
      <p2 ng-if="car.count >1">{{car.element}}</p2>
      <p2 ng-if="car.count >2">{{car.element}}</p2>
      <p2 ng-if="car.count >3">{{car.element}}</p2>
      <p2 ng-if="car.count >4">{{car.element}}</p2>
      <p2 ng-if="car.count >5">{{car.element}}</p2>
      <p2 ng-if="car.count >6">{{car.element}}</p2>
   </li>
```

but I would like to know if it is possible to do a general case in Angular (so I can apply it even if I don't know which number is going to appear in `car.count`)

You can check [the plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UKsDFNAwg5MdcykmnxhW?p=preview) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simple and pure JavaScript way:

```
<li ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <p2 ng-repeat="item in [].constructor(car.count) track by $index">{{car.element}}</p2>
</li>
```

Comment: I will mark it as valid as I think is the most optimal one. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested `ng-repeat` directives and a function that creates a new array of a specific length to acheive your desired result.

```
<li ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <p2 ng-repeat="t in arrayOfLength(car.count) track by $index">{{car.element}} </p2>
</li>
```

Controller

```
$scope.arrayOfLength = function(num){
    return new Array(num);
}
```

Working [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UOBDVrLHRqNmxge2hxfO?p=preview)

Comment: what a coincidence! we both had a same answer on same time, only 5 seconds difference.. You beat me! +1

Comment: This is a pretty elegant solution, I need to step my solution game up lol

Answer (score 1):

You can use another `ng-repeat` inside of you main ng-repeat and use a **custom filter** which returns empty array with a size of `car.count`...

```
<li ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <p2 ng-repeat="item in car | carCount track by $index">{{car.element}}</p2>
</li>
```

Here is our custom filter code **carCount**

```
app.filter('carCount', function() {
  return function (car) {
    return new Array(car.count);
  }
});
```

and here is your updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ro7CCGIbUOErM8pHClYD?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would need a way to do it so it would work with any value of count that I would not know in advance (for example, with count:20).

Comment: @Joe82 sorry I understood your question wrong check out updated answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="car in cars">
      <p2 ng-repeat="i in _.range(1,car.count)">{{car.element}}</p2>
</li>
```

And in your controller you have to add underscore (or a function that gives you a range) to the scope like this

```
$rootScope._ = _;
```

or

```
$scope.range = _.range
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array dynamically based on count provided by each car item. And then loop over that array and have `::` just for evaluate `createArray` function binding only once.

**Markup**

```
<li ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <p2 ng-repeat="item in ::createArray(car.count) track by $index">{{car.element}}</p2>
</li>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.createArray = function(count) {
    return new Array(count);
}
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1UfJC7PeT04tV93lYHcc?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can go about it by adding a function in your app.js that displays the cars by count.  So doing the following will give you your desired results:

**in app.js**

```
$scope.displayCarByCount = function(car) {
    var carString = '';
    for(var i= 0; i < car.count; i++) {
      carString += car.element + ' ';
    }
    return  carString;
 }
```

**in HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="car in cars">
     <p2>{{displayCarByCount(car)}}</p2>
 </li>
```

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HhCetNrtFeFE9kGEaqbl?p=preview) in case you don't just want to read.